# Asp.net Core Diagnostic Events in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Im am experimenting with Asp.net Core. I am using visual studio 2015 enterprise.
I set up two MVC projects. The first is targeting the .net-framework and the other runs on .net core runtime (dotnet.exe).

I noticed that when I run the app (targeting .net framework) in visual studio, the diagnostics-tools window shows all kinds of events e.g. which controller action was called or if model state was valid.

[image]

This diagnostics view does not show any kind of information, when I run a boilerplate mvc project template targeting .net core runtime.

See

[image]

I do understand that .net core applications are executed by the core runtime and not visual studio directly, but is it normal that visual studio does not recognize those diagnostic events anymore ?

If so, what is the recommended way of viewing or log away this information ?